# yadcf smart filtering with contains filter

Tags: datatables, yadcf

Is there a way to use smart filtering with `yadcf` + `DataTables`? I'm using regular text filters in `contains` filter mode. As far as I can see `yadcf` calls fnFilter with bSmart=false parameter when mode is contains.

I want to search just typing fragments of words in the filter input. If it's not a smart filter, it won't find anything if I just type in some fragments after each other.

I wonder if I just overlooked something. Otherwise I can open a feature issue on GitHub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's hard wired now, and possibly bSmart=true become default in the future for contains filters: https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/issues/148